# Expected value and variance of a stochastic process with transformed random variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, variance

> Let $Y\sim U(0,2\pi)$ be a random variable and consider a stochastic process $\{X_t,t\in\mathbb R\},$ where $X_t=a\sin(\omega t+Y)$ with $a>0,\omega>0$. Compute expected value and variance of this process.

I used $E(X_t)=a\sin(\omega t)E(\cos Y)+a\cos(\omega t)E(\sin Y),$ then separately computed densities of transformed variables $\cos Y,\sin Y$ and eventually $E(\cos Y)=E(\sin Y)=0.$ This also yields $\operatorname{Var}(X_t)=E((X_t-E(X_t))^2)=E(X_t^2)=\ldots$ (I didn't finish this because I'm lazy :)

But in retrospect, this seems to be clumsy. So I want to ask, is there a different way to determine the required moments?

Comment: $E(X_t)=\int_0^{2\pi} dy\ \dfrac{a}{2\pi} \sin(\omega t  + y).$

Comment: Heh, what? I don't get it.

Comment: like @WillM. said, that is by definition of expected value.

Next thing to note is: $\sin(\omega t + y) = \frac{e^{i(\omega+ty)}}{2}-\frac{e^{-i(\omega+ty)}{2}}{2}$. Hence $E[X_t] = \frac{1}{2}e^{i\omega/2}\phi(t)-\frac{1}{2}e^{-i\omega/2}\phi(-t)$ where $\phi$ is the characteristic function of $Y$ (you can look up what it is).

But actually it is probably way easier to just do the integral...